# Download only the files and folders in a subdirectory on the internet using wget

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying download files and directories inside a site at say https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ . What I want is that I get all the contents at this url, as in files and directories, exactly in the same way and store them in a directory named "dir" on my machine. The command I used is `wget -r --no-parent -P "dir" https://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` . But what this does is create folders in my directory as `dir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/..all the contents here..`. What I want is `dir/.. All the contents here..`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man wget`

> --cut-dirs=number

> Ignore number directory components.  This is useful for getting a fine-grained control over the directory where recursive retrieval will be saved.